# How do I increase an amount of digits after the point?

Tags: evaluation, precision-and-accuracy, digits

I have an expression such as:

```
Log[0.784637, 517.8796]*ArcTan[-1.112673]*0.4256^(-2.034)*Sqrt[3.567]
```

and I get 3 digits precision. I tried:

```
N[Log[0.784637, 517.8796]*ArcTan[-1.112673]*0.4256^(-2.034)*Sqrt[3.567],10]
```

and

```
x=Log[0.784637, 517.8796]*ArcTan[-1.112673]*0.4256^(-2.034)*Sqrt[3.567];
Round[#,0.0000000001]& /@ x
```

but neither works (still get 3 digits). What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `NumberForm`, `AccountingForm` and similar.

Comment: Note that it doesn't really make sense to ask for more digits. Assuming e.g. `2.034` means `2.034±0.0005` (since you don't know the next digit), the final result of your expression is `231.98±0.11`, so you barely know the first digit after the decimal point. You can see this by doing `Log["0.784637", "517.8796"]*ArcTan["-1.112673"]*"0.4256"^("-2.034")*Sqrt["3.567"] /. s_String :> Around@s`, which effectively constructs `Around` objects for all the numbers you have given, and computes the error based on first order error propagation

Comment: By default, Mathematica doesn't print all the digits of machine numbers. Use `InputForm` to see the full number.